# JSESSIONID PHP Curl Request

Tags: php, cookies, curl, jsessionid, curl-multi

I am trying to send a multi curl request to an api in order to retrieve data. This specific api requires a proper JSESSIONID cookie to be passed into the headers for it to work correctly.

The function I am using to send the request is:

```
function sendMultiRequest($data) {

    // initialize array of curl handles
    $curl_handles = array();
    // returned data
    $result = array();

    // initialize multi handle
    $multi_handle = curl_multi_init();

    //$cookie = generateCookie();

    $headers = array(
        'Content-type: application/json',
        'Cookie: JSESSIONID=39DDF47143F20CA952555027CD5F5EA2'
    );

    // loop through $data and create curl handles
    // then add them to the multi-handle
    foreach ($data as $key => $val) {

        $curl_handles[$key] = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($curl_handles[$key], CURLOPT_URL, $val);
        curl_setopt($curl_handles[$key], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl_handles[$key], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl_handles[$key], CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);


        curl_multi_add_handle($multi_handle, $curl_handles[$key]);

    }

    // execute the handles
    $running = null;
    do {
        curl_multi_exec($multi_handle, $running);
    } while($running > 0);


    // get content and remove handles
    foreach($curl_handles as $key => $val) {
        $result[$key] = json_decode(curl_multi_getcontent($val), TRUE);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($multi_handle, $val);

    }

    // close curl_multi
    curl_multi_close($multi_handle);

    return $result;
}
```

I dont think it is the functions problem because my other multi requests work. But when I try to access the api, I don;t get data unless I pass in a correct JSESSIONID.

I know this because I am currently using the Advanced REST Client Google Chrome Extension and when I use the Cookie Request Header that the extension passes, the function works. However, the api credentials expire and so I need to programattically create and use a JSESSIONID.

I understand that I must use the curl opt COOKIEJAR and COOKIE somehow, but I am not too sure as I am new to this.

Answer (score 2):

You only use `CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION` when you are trying to simulate the start of a new session.  By doing this cURL will not load any session cookies from the cookie jar/file.

You also need to specify the cookie jar file to be used via `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`

So building on your example:

```
// then add them to the multi-handle
foreach ($data as $key => $val) {

    $curl_handles[$key] = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl_handles[$key], CURLOPT_URL, $val);
    curl_setopt($curl_handles[$key], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl_handles[$key], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl_handles[$key], CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/path/to/cookie/file');
    // do this only if you need to force a new session and not load session cookie from cookie jar
    curl_setopt($curl_handles[$key], CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);


    curl_multi_add_handle($multi_handle, $curl_handles[$key]);

}
```

You should NEVER have to manually set your session id cookie value.

Comment: How would this help me create a Cookie named 'JSESSIONID'?

Comment: @Karthik you would not need to create the cookie the remote server sends the cookie on your first request of the session. That cookie gets stored in the cookie jar and would automatically be sent with subsequent requests.

Comment: The documentation for the API that I am using say that I must supply JSESSIONID cookie on the header. Will creation the CookieJar do this for me?

Comment: @Karthik How can one get a session ID until one has called a service for the first time to initiate a session? Sessions are typically initiated by the server and propagated via cookies. Is there some API you need to call first to initiate a session?

Comment: Initially I have to call an OAuth API every hour to get the credentials I need to access the rest of the api. However, all this OAuth really gives me is a token. Nothing really about a session.

Comment: @Karthik Sounds like a question for the owner of the API.  I have never worked with a service where the client specifies their session ID.  This would be very unusual and potentially insecure.